# Структура файла .class

Tags: java, классы, компилятор

Какую информацию можно получить от уже скомпилированного java файла .class? Какие данные там хранятся в явном виде?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я ничего не забыл и правильно понимаю официальную документацию (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html), хранятся там в явном виде все строки, информация о предке, методах, интерфейсах и полях. Может и еще что.

Comment: там есть таблица, в которой всё подробно расписано

Comment: @Nox именно поэтому я и привел ссылку на документацию.

Answer (score 1):

- Свойства файла: определяющее тип файла «волшебное слово» 0xCAFEBABE и версия формата;
- Пул констант – содержит все используемые имена методов и классов в специальном формате, и прочую символьную информацию. В других местах используются только ссылки на элементы пула;
- Основные свойства класса: флаги доступа, имя этого класса, его предка, интерфейсов;
- Внутреннее содержимое: список полей класса и байткод методов
- Атрибуты класса;

[Взято отсюда](https://itsobes.ru/JavaSobes/35.html)